# How to #define a function to be replaced by another?

Tags: c

How to #define a function to be replaced by another?

For example, if I have a function Stuff(int numbers) and would like to replace it with Stuff2(int numbers, int otherNumbers).

So, when Stuff() is called, Stuff2() is used instead.

Comment: What would you put in place of the missing parameter?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Using #define is a basic global text replacement.

```
#define Stuff(number) Stuff2(number,0)
```

The zero is here for illustration; replace it with whatever the appropriate default is. If necessary, you could even call a function or use more macro magic to compute it.

**Update**

So, following the commentary, OP is trying to redirect main().

This is a technique with a highly-specific use-case. The first thing to remember is that main() is not a normal function. That’s right, main() is *special*.

As a result, you cannot just replace main() and expect things to work happily. There must be a main(), and it must be declared according to one of your compiler’s accepted variations. (IMO, you should prefer to use one of the two variations required by the C Standard.)

**Intercepting the user’s main()**

The technique is commonly used by libraries that want to have an app-level control over your application, but want you to think that everything is normal.

They do this by declaring main() in the *library’s* code, and #defining main to something else in the header so that when *you* write "main()" it is actually a different function. For example:

```
// quuxlib.c

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  int exit_code = 0;

  // library does initializations here
  ...

  // call the user's main(), LOL
  exit_code = UsersMain( argc, argv );

  // perform cleanup
  ...

  return exit_code;
}
```

The library's header:

```
// quuxlib.h

#define main UsersMain

...
```

And now the user’s code *looks* normal:

```
#include "quuxlib.h"

int main( int argc, char** argv )  // This is actually UsersMain()!
{
  // Use quuxlib without any further thought
}
```

**Caveats and Best Practices**

This technique is, IMHO, *bad design*. It seeks to obscure what is actually happening. A better library design would be explicit, and either:

- Require you to properly initialize and finalize the library in your main()
- Expect you to use an explicit entry procedure

The former is preferred, as it gets along with all kinds of stuff better. For example, Tcl hooks things properly. Here you simply create an interpreter, use it, and terminate normally.

```
#include "tcl.h"

int main()
{
  Tcl_Interp* interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
  int status = Tcl_Eval( interp, "puts {Hello world!}" );
  return 0;
}
```

Tcl also goes one step further, providing [Tcl_Main](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/Tcl_Main.htm) and [Tcl_AppInit](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/AppInit.htm) to make life very easy. [See an example here](http://www.gibmonks.com/practical-programming/ch44lev1sec6.html).

Using an explicit entry procedure is the very same thing as the main() replacement trick, just without pretending anything:

```
#include "quuxlib.h"

int AppMain()  // required by QuuxLib
{
  // my main program here
  ...

  return 0;
}
```

**The problems**

To finish, the problems with re#defining main are:

- it obscures what is really happening
- it uses a global macro replacement

Good design doesn't try to hide things from you. A global macro replacement is also bad. In this case, "main" is not a reserved word. You could have a valid local identifier called "main". Using a global macro replacement obviates that possibility.

Finally, having a library provide explicit initialization and finalization procedures rather than take over main *increases* the flexibility available to the user. A library that takes your main() cannot be used with another library that does the same, nor can it really be trusted to handle things that can go wrong (IMHO) as well as a library the provides proper and explicit hooks for the library user to handle that kind of stuff.

The trade-off is pretty for common cases vs versatility.

Well, I think I’m pretty firmly into rambling now, so it’s time to stop...

Comment: So, lets say I'm trying to replace main() with main2(). Currently it can't find the main2 and is exiting. I am trying to do the following: #define main() main2()

Comment: `main()` is your *entry point*, I'm not sure you would ever want to redefine it. It's possible to specify a separate entry point, but this is sounding a lot like an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish?